# work in .xib file not saved

Tags: xcode4.2

[image]

when im doing work in .xib file and after finishing i tried to save it but it continuously showing the message that the document could not be saved.Please help with this

Comment: I want you to check couple of things: 
1) have you tried to disconnect all your IBOutlets and delegate/datasource etc before save ? 
2) Do you have admin rights ?
3) Are other XIB files getting save ?
4) Try to remove picker viewer and then save it... we will troubleshoot later if it works..